# Returning Pixel Value as "None"

Tags: python

I have the following line of code:

```
img = cv.imread("c:/users/admin/downloads/sack.jpg", 1)
```

It is not reading anything into `img`. `img` is showing `None`. `sack.jpg` exists, and is an image file.

Comment: which version of python? What is cv?

Comment: Do you have permissions to read `admin`s user folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import cv2

image_path = r"c:/users/admin/downloads/sack.jpg"
assert os.path.isfile(image_path)
img = cv2.imread(image_path, 1)
```

Either the assert will fail, or the read will succeed, or the file is not a valid image.
Notice the `r` preceding the path.

Also notice `cv2`, not `cv`.

Comment: I noticed that `r` preceding the path. Do you have an explanation for it? I know it disables escaping backslashes, so they can be used as regular characters. But ... there *are* no backslashes. So, why point it out?

Comment: Strictly speaking, someone can still erase the file between the `assert` and the `imread()`.

Comment: @dedObed The assert isn't there to make sure the file exists against a deletion, it is there because `imread` fails silently on non existing files, and I want to make it fail non silently. You are, of course, correct.

Comment: @usr2564301 Just a best practice for paths. Absolute paths in development mode tend to change, and this just saves time. I actually didn't notice the path doesn't have backslashes, and this `r` makes sure I never *have to* notice.

Comment: Of course you are getting an assertion error, that is why the assert is there. It means there is no file in that path. Make sure there is an image in that exact path.

Answer (score 0):

### **EDITED**

This worked for me on WINDOWS:

```
import cv2

path = r'c:/users/admin/downloads/sack.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path)
cv2.imshow('imgTitle',img)

cv2.waitKey()
```

you can check how cv2.imread works [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/).

Note that:

1. It's (**cv2**) not cv.
2. Add `cv.waitKey()` so your image won't open and close very fast.
3. Anyway using the manual path writing is not very practical in the
   real time applications,  insted of that you can try using libraries 
   like **os** and **pathlib**, it's very recommended too.

Comment: you actually don't have to use back slashes. not on windows anyway

Comment: @Gulzar in the matter of fact, that depends on what do you wanna do with the path you are providing, because some functions in Pyhton transfer the slashes into it's right form depending on the OS you're using. The normal path in Windows takes Back slashes, but in Linux and Mac it takes forward slashes.

Comment: @RameshRavula if it's not giving any errors then add this line of code: " 
  cv2.waitkey() ", of course without the quotation marks, because otherwise the image will open and close so fast.

Comment: @RameshRavula I edited the answer and  it should work because it works on my machine, so check it carefully!, and next time my friend try to search the web before writing a question, or right your questions well!, otherwise they will give you negative rating. hope that will help